# Connect SSIS to Heroku PostgreSQL database

Tags: ssis, odbc, heroku-postgres

I am unable to set up a connection manager to link to the Postgres database. I've downloaded and installed the pgosql driver, tried to add it to both 32 and 64 bit ODBC data sources but I get the 'FATAL: not pg_hba.conf entry for host ...'

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to select 'allow' in the SSL box when setting up the driver.

Note that, in my case, SSIS could not identify the data source name when I added the postgreSQL data source to the 64 bit version of ODBC data sources but it worked with the 32 bit version.